# open source CMS and server for video streaming platform

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, streaming, mpeg-dash, dash.js

I have to propose a platform that allows streaming video services employing the MPEEG-DASH standard. This platform blocks must be implemented with open source tools. I proposed FFmpeg to encode and MP4Box/GPAC tool for encryption and packaging. For the DRM case my propose is to use Widewine (I didn’t find any other open source tool) which is compatible with dash.js (the player proposed by me), it can be integrated to Chrome and according to CastLabs it’s also compatible with MP4Box. So, I have to select an open source CMS, and at the same time I need it to be compatible with dash.js. I read that it’s possible to add any JavaScript to these CMS, that it’s only necessary to create some modules to do so. I’d like to know which one of the following CMS you suggest me: MediaDrop, Drupal or Wordpress.
I also have some doubts about the server. I know that in order to offer this service it only takes a traditional HTTP server. In a first moment I chose Nginx over Apache because the latter presents some problems associated to performance (the server will receive a large amount of simultaneous requests), nevertheless, I discarded Nginx (Nginx-rtmp module) due to its constraints: it’s only for live streaming (I need the service to be offered also on demand) and the inputs must be RTMP. I found something about Nginx-based VOD packager, do you know if this one can be used as a server to offer live and on demand streaming service?

Answer (score 2):

when it comes to DRM you will need other systems than just Widevine to reach all browser platforms, e.g. PlayReady for IE/EDGE or FairPlay with HLS for Safari. Here you can find a overview of the DRM systems for the different browsers: https://bitmovin.com/player-drm-support/

When you already use ffmpeg + MP4Box to encode and package the content, you don't need a dedicated VoD packager support on your webserver, you can just the DASH/HLS content on the HTTP Webserver. Here you can find a tutorial for x264 + MP4Box, maybe that's useful: https://bitmovin.com/mp4box-dash-content-generation-x264/